# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference at maps

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, nullpointerexception

I am working android application that has many screens that contain maps, and when I work on some of those screens and try to open them, sometimes it crashed with bellow error, and can't do anything or test screen that I work on, what I do to work around this error by deleting app data, and I open the screen again after many times it crashing again and I got tired from deleting app data, log in again entering OTP etc.

I need a solution for this cause clearing app data its not a good option.

here's my stack trace

> 022-03-16 10:40:19.976 9168-9230/com.interface_fze.dawana.pharmacy E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
> 2022-03-16 10:40:22.398 9168-9327/com.interface_fze.dawana.pharmacy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 1022
> Process: com.interface_fze.dawana.pharmacy, PID: 9168
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
> at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.aj.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@220618097@22.06.18 (190400-0):11)
> at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.aj.(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@220618097@22.06.18 (190400-0):3)
> at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.g.(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@220618097@22.06.18 (190400-0):18)
> at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bs.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@220618097@22.06.18 (190400-0):14)
> at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.av.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@220618097@22.06.18 (190400-0):44)
> 2022-03-16 10:40:22.490 9168-9168/com.interface_fze.dawana.pharmacy E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted